# JqueryMobile Remote Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I am using this piece of code to create an autocompletable combo with JqueryMobile. It works fine, but now I want to add the message "Type at least three characters" to it whenever the user has typed something with less than 3 chars.

I tried with this code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
        $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                url : "myjson/api/",
                dataType : "json",
                crossDomain : true,
                encoding : "utf-8",
                data : {
                    q : $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
            html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
        else if (value && value.length > 0) {
            html = '<li><a>Type at least three characters</a></li>';
            $ul.html(html);
            $ul.listview("refresh");
            $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
            }
        });
     });
```

Which just adds the `else if` part to what is already done on the demo page. When I type a single character, I do get the "Type at least three characters" message, but if I type 2, the message disappears! I checked with Firebug's js debug and execution goes through the `else if` branch, adds the html to the UL list, but as soon as `ul.trigger("updatelayout")` is called, it disappears. Oddly enough, commenting that line out does not solve it: in that case, it disappears after the refresh call.

What is weirder is that it works with 1 char only.

EDIT: Also, straight out of the box and even in the demo showcase, the refresh layer that's supposed to be shown when making the AJAX request is never shown

Comment: `else if (value && value.length <= 3)` try this.

Comment: same problem. Again, the condition should not be the problem, the code is actually going through that branch.

Comment: Well that makes it even weirder since I have exactly the same code than that fiddle.

Comment: it works once and stop working again, too weird. I've removed my comment because it's not 100% functioning.

Comment: It works if you type in text that's in the "Type at least three characters". What it appears to be doing is applying the typed text as a filter for list elements.

Comment: exactly, you need to put it outside the auto complete.

Comment: Well that's difficult because if putting it outside I loose all styling

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41411/discussion-between-omar-and-michelreap)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, the problem was that the listview is filtering its elements according to what the user has typed, so if you type two characteres and those are not in the info message ("Type at least 3 characters") then the list element will be hidden.

I solved this with a clumsy workaround consisting on appending the typed value to the info message as a hidden span:

```
html = '<li><span style="display:none">' + value + '</span>Type at least 3 characters.</li>';
                        $ul.html(html);
                        $ul.listview("refresh");
                        $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
```

This way it works.

Someone should fix the original demo though.